# Are questions related to certain "practices" which might be "superstitions" likely to be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

I recently asked a [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10870/what-is-the-significance-of-odd-numbers-in-hinduism), which was promptly closed as off topic, citing:

> This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the
>   scope defined in the help center

The question falls in the following category according to the help center:
**"Questions about Hindu practices."**

I also made a comment supporting this:

> Even though you may consider this question to be falling under
>   superstition, but you can't deny that 'odd' features prominently in
>   daily hindu rituals. If no specific references are found in any of the
>   scriptures, 'no' would be a simple answer

Hence I was just looking for 'any' references from the Hindu scriptures. If there are none, No is the answer. Closing the question is not the solution.

I would like to mention that I am not new to the SE community, and I always read the help center of a community that I join, before asking a question. Also I am aware of the cascading effect of close votes- when a high rep user votes to close a question, others blindly follow.

While browsing through the community I see many same spirited questions which were never closed. Some examples are [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/myth-customs-related-to-shaving-hairwash)(with various versions, which were never closed as duplicates), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10116/why-women-are-not-allowed-to-enter-sabarimala?rq=1), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/why-do-some-hindus-observe-fast-during-the-month-of-shravan?rq=1)....

Comment: This question have 4 upvote/ 1 downvote and 5 close vote with one reopen vote. Community seems divided on it and i did noticed it getting close vote but not when it got closed.  I think it can work and i am reopening it.

Comment: Thanks @AnkitSharma.

Comment: @AnkitSharma There are many popular customs that have evolved over time. Many are done at a local or regional level and can vary from sect to sect with no foundation in scripture. Many of these types of questions add no knowledge to the community and only bring off-topic comments by new users. In Philosophy SE, sometimes controversial questions are protected by moderators so that only users with 50 or 100 points (I don't remember what the exact amount is) can leave comments. That might be a vehicle for these type of questions.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Protect is only needed when it get targeted by bad answer and till now it doesn't even have an answer. I can understand your feeling toward the question but we already have this kind of question and till we don't have common question of disallowing them closing open and keeping other will only create confusion. WE will keep an eye on it, it it ever needed protection , we will do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I feel that your question was perfectly valid. Backed up by comments. I upvoted it as I too wanted to know, because many of the practices/superstitions I too follow. :-)
As of now I have voted for re-opening. If this Q was closed due to [superstition](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superstition) then it can't be closed as "off-topic", because it's still a valid tag of this site!

BTW, There are numerous answers for the similar question in Quora here:
[Why do Indians give cash gifts in numbers such as 51, 101, and 501?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Indians-give-cash-gifts-in-numbers-such-as-51-101-and-501)

In any such case, you should first try to flag your question for moderator attention. In your Q, no moderator was involved for closing, hence you still have a hope to get it reopened. If that doesn't work, then posting a query here is the best way to bring it in light. Also you should try to put more generic title to your complain, so that it helps others to know specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for providing a better title. Mine looked like a rant ;)